# Install NTL without root privileges and modify it's build path in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, ntl

I want to install the [HElib library](https://github.com/shaih/HElib) (for which NTL is a dependency) on a remote machine on which I do not have root privileges, i.e. I cannot use "sudo make install" to install NTL. The NTL library is not installed in `usr/local` as per HElib's [makefile](https://github.com/shaih/HElib/blob/master/src/Makefile).

```
LDLIBS = -L/usr/local/lib $(NTL) $(GMP) -lm
```

How can I install NTL without root privileges and how do I modify the Makefile in order for it to run?

Comment: typically when compiling prior to executing make you execute ./configure which in turn synthesizes a fresh Makefile particular to your needs ... examine file configure to see environment variable PREFIX or a similarly named var which often controls full pathname of install location ... then define configure mentioned env var prior to executing ./configure ... finally execute make to engage that fresh Makefile ... this compile pattern is very common across many libraries

Answer (score 1):

In NTL's `makefile` you can change the line:

```
DEF_PREFIX=/usr/local
```

to become

```
DEF_PREFIX=$(HOME)/dev
```

Then you should be able to set in HElib's Makefile:

```
LDLIBS = -L$(HOME)/dev/lib $(NTL) $(GMP) -lm
```

Replace `dev` with the path to your development folder in your $HOME directory.